# Create certificate from public key

Tags: c#, encryption-asymmetric

There is a method : GetPublicKeyString from X509Certificate, if we pass the output which is hex base 64 , can we create a public key certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

The `X509Certificate` instance is already a "public key certificate", in that it's an X.509 certificate that isn't an "attribute certificate" (a much, much less commonly used type of certificate from the X.509 specification)

Certificates in .NET can have an associated private key, but they're really not part of the certificate.  So, if you meant that you want to create a certificate instance that is guaranteed to not know about a private key, then you want to do

```
X509Certificate2 publicOnly = new X509Certificate2(cert.RawData);
```

(Or, if you're really using `X509Certificate` and can't access RawData, you can also get it from `cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert)`.

The output of `cert.GetPublicKeyString()` is of a format that depends on `cert.GetKeyAlgorithm()`.  For RSA keys (1.2.840.113549.1.1.1) `GetPublicKeyString` produces an `RSAPublicKey` value, which is sufficient to hydrate a key object (e.g. the `ImportRSAPublicKey` method on the `RSA` class).  For DSA keys, it's not, and you also need to interpret `cert.GetKeyAlgorithmParameters()`.  Though, for any built-in algorithm there's no need to use these values at all.  `cert.GetRSAPublicKey()` and friends will do that work for you.